# Чему/чем обязан вашему вниманию/вашим вниманием?

Tags: падежи, управление

Итак, какой набор падежных форм является нормативным для фраз, построенных по такому образцу? Мне кажется логичным поставить вопросительное слово в форму Д. п., а дополнение - в форму Т. п.: "Чему обязан вашим вниманием?" Однако в литературе можно встретить компоненты этого выражения, склоненные во всех падежах: *"Чем [Т. п.] обязан такой честью [Т. п.]?"(Александр Савельев. Аркан для букмекера); "Итак, ― начал Каштанов, ― чем [Т. п.] обязан вашему назойливому вниманию [Д. п.]?" (Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Тихие омуты); "Чему [Д. п.] обязан удовольствием [Т. п.] видеть вас вновь, да еще в столь ранний час? (Леонид Юзефович. Дом свиданий)*.
Вариативность падежных форм элементов построенных по такой схеме вопросов заставляет меня сомневаться в нормативности предложенного мной варианта или по крайней мере в его единственности как варианта, соответствующего нормам языка.
Может быть, нет ошибки в употреблении других падежей, а есть семантические различия между разными комбинациями падежных форм?

Comment: Лермонтов: "Нет, лучше бы мне век остаться в этой презренной солдатской шинели, которой, может быть, я обязан вашим вниманием...". Так понял, что есть две формы: "обязан кому/чему кем/чем", "обязан кем/чем кому/чему". Примеры: "обязан шинели вниманием", "обязан вниманием шинели".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из Словаря трудностей РЯ Розенталя и Теленковой:
Обязанный, кр. ф. –ан, –ана, –ано, –аны. Управление: кому, чему, чем.

(Чем?)Своим спасением он обязан (чему?)случаю. Чему я обязан вашим посещением?
«Чем» и «чему» – разные направления порождения обязанности, разные значения, разная коннотация - отрицательная и положительная.

1.Чем обязан? - фразеологизм. Чем ( какими обстоятельствами, какой причиной) я обязан вашему посещению, визиту? (значение "по какой причине вы пришли?")- просматривается сдержанное неудовольствие, его обязали, вынудили, возвели в долг.

2.Чему (каким обстоятельствам, какой причине) я обязан, что/кого благодарить (перед какими обстоятельствами я в долгу за счастье Вас лицезреть?)- а) либо откровенная радость, б) либо раболепное лицемерие, в) либо ирония над значимостью пожаловавшего  лица. В общем, декларация (или намёк на) чувства благодарности.

У слова Обязанный два значения: 1) заставленный, повинный, вынужденный; 
2) получивший, достигший чего-либо благодаря кому-либо или чему-либо, благодарный,  признательный.

Чем обязан - в чём повинен, что обязало?; чему обязан? - кому-чему должен быть благодарен?

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.

> Чем обязан? - фразеологизм

То есть это семантически нейтральное выражение, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нейтральное в официальном общении, приятелю так не скажешь, обычно официальному лицу или нежелательному гостю, с кем не хочешь иметь близких отношений.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, я просто подумала, что может быть какая-то разница между лаконичным "Чем обязан?" без указания, чему именно обязан, и распространенным "Чем обязан вашему вниманию?".

Answer (score 2):

1. Словарь предлагает нам следующую форму: обязан кому/чему чем. Из этого делаем вывод, что падежи должны быть разными.
2. Мы имеем два предмета: мое качество - ваше внимание, и они должны вписаться в следующую схему: нечто ценное, полученное благодаря чему-то. Интересно, что два исходных предмета могут меняться местами, и из этого следуют два возможных речевых варианта.

Вариант 1. Ценность - это ваше внимание, я имею его благодаря своему какому-то качеству. Тогда мы говорим: Чему я обязан вашим (ценным) вниманием. Это выражение признательности за внимание.

Вариант 2. Ценность - это какое-то мое качество, которое и привлекло ваше (не слишком ценное) внимание. Тогда мы говорим: Чем я обязан вашему вниманию. Это выражение определенного высокомерия.

Comment: > Ценность - это какое-то мое качество, которое и привлекло ваше (не слишком ценное) внимание. Тогда мы говорим: Чем я обязан вашему вниманию. 

Мол, чем хорошим в своей жизни я обязан вашему вниманию? Какие, мол, ваши услуги обязывают меня уделять вам внимание? 
Хорошее объяснение, спасибо.

Comment: Попробую уточнить область применения. 1) Чем обязан вашему вниманию (Что вас интересует). Нейтральный или официальный вариант. Логически выделен предмет внимания. 2) Чему обязан вашим вниманием? Неофициальный вопрос, дополнительно выражающий уважение к собеседнику.

Comment: > Попробую уточнить область применения. 1) Чем обязан вашему вниманию (Что вас интересует). Нейтральный или официальный вариант. Логически выделен предмет внимания. 2) Чему обязан вашим вниманием? Неофициальный вопрос, дополнительно выражающий уважение к собеседнику.

Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Мне к Людмиле добавить особо и нечего, тут действительно два разных случая употребления.

Только вспомню знаменитый пример косноязычия Горького: "Всему хорошему во мне я обязан книгам". Если кто не знает, то пролетарский писатель явно смешал два случая: чем обязан и чему обязан. Должно быть ""всем хорошим...". "Книгам" - чему, а вот "все хорошее" - это чем.

Все, что на данный момент удалось установить, авторы, приводящие  грамматически правильную версию ссылаются на статью "О книге", появишуюся в 1925 г. во французском переводе, а на русском опубликованную в 1941 г.

Если ссылка сработает, то даю, если нет, - гугл её находит без проблем по ключемым словам "О книге" "Всем хорошим" "1925"

http://books.google.ru/books?id=UZqhAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT1165&lpg=PT1165&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%22+%22%D0%9E++%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%22+1925&source=bl&ots=c90Po-j-5g&sig=qjWftemTZ5F5pZmFwmoRMVcMDvw&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=0Xj9UpzyCunh4QTZ7oGoAQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%22%20%22%D0%9E%20%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%22%201925&f=false

Если удастся найти источник, приводящий более ранние данные, то причина расхождений становится очевидна. С французского перевели "правильно", а "всему хорошему" дается по некоему оригинальному тексту.

Вот пока все.

Comment: Простите,а где Вы это прочитали - про косноязычие Горького?Да ещё о том, что пример знаменитый? Нигде, кроме сайтов в Интернете,не видела фразы с ошибкой, везде  правильный афоризм , да и на грамотных сайтах, вот например: http://thelure.ru/maksim-gorkij-o-knige.html  Это не Горький, это авторы сайтов косноязычны

Comment: Людмила, в наше время эту фразу еще в школе проходили - с подробными обсуждениями, что и как надо в ней понимать. 
Смотрите собрание сочинений того времени, у меня под рукой нет.
А а иначе откуда бы в интернет попало?

*ЗЫ Любите же Dы поспорить (С)Людмила.*

Comment: Все, что на данный момент удалось устаносить, исходынй

Comment: А почему вы не даете более подробного комментария по существу вопроса?
Вот стандарт: Чему я обязан вашим вниманием? А почему существует второй вариант: Чем я обязан вашему вниманию?  Область применения двух выражений обозначена, а какова их грамматика, почему падежи поменялись местами?

Comment: behemothus, да я не спорю, просто время у нас,похоже, одно, а я первый раз об этом слышу. У меня остался на память очень старый учебник литературы(реликвия советских дней), я сразу туда, а там всё правильно, никаких ошибок, рукописей его, к сожалению, не встречала.

Answer (score 1):

"Чему обязан вашим вниманием?" - это не по-русски. Обязанным можно быть чем-то-то - кому-то, а не наоборот. Обязанный ОБ’ЯЗАННЫЙ , -ая, -ое; -ан, -ана. 1. с Имеющий что-н. своей обязанностью, долгом. Обязан помочь. Обязан подчиняться. 2. кому (чему) чем. Достигший чего-н. благодаря кому-чему-н.; признательный, благодарный за что-н. Человек, всем обязанный своему учителю. Многим обязан школе. Он обязан успехом своему трудолюбию. Я вам очень обязан (благодарен за одолжение). (Словрь русского языка Ожегова и Шведовой.)

Comment: Я обязан успехом  своему трудолюбию (я имею успех вследствие чего)? - Я обязан вашим вниманием чему (я имею ваше внимание вследствие чего)? Внимание и предмет внимания поменялись местами, и фраза из нейтральной превратилась в особо вежливую, где внимание собеседника представляет особую ценность.