# Как правильно: чему обязан или чем обязан

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно: чему обязан или чем обязан?

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30458 - здесь посмотрите.

Answer (score 3):

Допустим, входит в дом или комнату незнакомец. После обмена приветствиями хозяин спросит:

**– Чем обязан?** [*не* чему!]

Вы ведь именно это хотели спросить?

Comment: А, допустим, без обмена входит.

Comment: Без обмена?! Тогда хозяин имеет полное право на "позвольте вам выйти вон".

Answer (score 2):

Смотря с какой целью вы хотите воспользоваться подобным выражением.

1. "**Чему обязан** (удовольствием вас видеть и т.п.)?" - вежливое выражение, обычно требующее полной формы. Есть и английский вариант (To what do I owe the pleasure of your company today?).
2. "**Чем обязан**?" - выражение лёгкого неудовольствия от прихода незваного гостя. Существуют разные толкования его буквального смысла, но поскольку неизбежно возникает вопрос "*кто и кому обязан*?" (естественно, *я* адресату), то трудно отделаться от ощущения, что это дипломатичный вариант грубости: "Я *вам* что, должен что-то? Зачем пришли?" К этому выражению трудно подобрать расширенную форму по аналогии с первым случаем - она обычно приводит к "несварению" падежей.

Answer (score 1):

ОБЯЗАН **кому - чему,  чем**. *Чем я обязан? Своим спасением он обязан случаю;. Я знаю, что обязан успехами моими... уменью работать, любви к труду. (М.Г.)*

Д.Э. Розенталь. "Справочник по русскому языку. Управление в русском языке". М., 2003